# Read a df, split each cell and append to a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, csv

I am working on a csv file that has multiple columns. 
The file looks something like this...

```
A,B,C
1,'x;y;z','e;f;g'
2,'w;x;y','r;s;t'
3,'','p;q;r'
```

Each cell in the file has a string that is separated by ";".

I want to create a single list by reading each cell and splitting each cell based on the separator.

I have been able to do this but there are performance issues.

The csv file is huge and so I am looking for an optimized version.

The columns names are known upfront. My code is given below

My current solution is 
Make a list reading all the rows from each column
Flatten the list
split the items in list if the item is string,append to a new list
remove duplicates from the list

```
import pandas as pd

from io import StringIO
from collections import Iterable
import operator


csv_path ='my_dir'
# load the data with pd.read_csv
dataDF = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
dataDF.fillna(" ")
result=[]
cols=['A','B','C']

for i in cols:
    result.append(dataDF[i].tolist())

result=reduce(operator.concat, result)
print(result)
my_list=[]
for token in result:
    if isinstance(token, str):
        my_list.append(token.split(";"))

my_list=reduce(operator.concat, my_list)
my_list=list(set(my_list))
```

Comment: for starters you could define `my_list` as a `set()` from the beginning. `my_list.append(token.split(";"))` would then be `my_set.add(token.split(";"))`. and add the end you would do `my_list = list(my_set)`

Comment: Besides, *fillna* is not assigned, so it won't work (requires *inplace=True*).
I'm not sure if I understand completely the problem here, but seems like 
df[col].str.split(';') and the rest of .str machinery will work here just fine.

Comment: @OlegO I have added the sample file structure. Hope it explains what am I trying to do. My code works. But its slow. I am looking for a optimized solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many repeated values, this will probably go faster.

```
from itertools import chain

# load the data with pd.read_csv
dataDF = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['x;y;z', 'w;x;y', ''], 'C': ['e;f;g', 'r;s;t', 'p;q;r']})
dataDF.fillna(" ", inplace=True)
results_set = set()
for i in dataDF.columns:
    try:
        results_set.update(chain(*dataDF[i].str.split(';').values))
    except AttributeError:
        pass
print(results_set)
```

Comment: Yup. This one did the trick. Thanks a ton for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
from itertools import chain

# load the data with pd.read_csv
dataDF = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': ['x;y;z', 'w;x;y', ''], 'C': ['e;f;g', 'r;s;t', 'p;q;r']})
dataDF.fillna(" ", inplace=True)
list_of_lists = []
for i in dataDF.columns:
    try:
        list_of_lists.extend(dataDF[i].str.split(';').values)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
print(set(chain(*list_of_lists)))
```

Comment: Thanks. In my csv file there are approx 100k rows. There are 15 columns and each cell consists of a string with 30 items seperated by ";". I have run the above code and it has been running for more than 15 minutes now. I am on Windows 10 laptop with 8 GB RAM.